# Selenium webdriver:select a "div" from many "div"s that dynamically change the absolute path

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I need some help in selecting a div form many div's that for every session number of div's are changing.

For example:

- one time a have the div in that position(absolute path): /html/body/div[97]
- other time in that position (absolute path):/html/body/div[160]
- and so on...

At a moment only one div is active and the other div's are hidden.

I attached a picture to show the code.

I try the xpath below but doesn't work,I get the error "no such element: Unable to locate element ...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class=\'ui-selectmenu-menu ui-selectmenu-open\']/ul/li[1]")).click();
```

[Picture with html code is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA3N1.png)

Comment: you probably need to wait for that element to become visible.

Comment: Like is shows in the picture is active(is not gray-out).I try to click on it after the drop down menu is activated.

Comment: but you haven't told webdriver to wait using WebDriverWait until method.  If you're not attached to xpath, try the CSS selector "div.ui-selectmenu-open ul li:nth-of-type(1)"

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is great if you expect the target element to be in the exact location every time the page is displayed. However, CSS is the way to go if the content is constantly changing.

In the example below I have found the DIV and the Element that you highlighted in your screen capture.

```
    WebElement targetElementDiv = null;
    WebElement targetElement = null;

    targetElementDiv = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='ui-selectmenu-menu ui-selectmenu-open']"));
    if (targetElementDiv != null) {
         targetElement = targetElementDiv.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='ui-menu-item ui-state-focus'])");
    }
```

Comment: I'v got syntax error at class=['ui-selectmenu-menu ui-selectmenu-open'] and class=['ui-menu-item ui-state-focus'].

Comment: I forgot to add the double quotes. Sorry

Comment: Something is not OK ,this error is reported:"invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"

Comment: I placed the opening square bracket in the wrong place. I have edited the code.